# Make function pointer to std::min with std::initializer_list

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl, function-pointers

I want to make a function pointer and initialize it in the constructor.

If the type_ is Min, find the minimal of any inputs.

If the type_ is Max, find the maximum of any inputs.

I write down the following codes, but it won't compile in the VS 2014, which C++ compiler version is MSVC 19.0.23506.0.

```
uint32_t (*compare) (std::initializer_list<const uint32_t> init_list);

if (Min == type_) {
  compare = std::min<std::initializer_list<const uint32_t>>;
} else if (Max == type_) {
  compare = std::max<std::initializer_list<const uint32_t>>;
}
```

The errors are below:

```
error C2563: mismatch in formal parameter list
error C2568: '=': unable to resolve function overload
note: could be '_Ty std::min(std::initializer_list<_Elem>,_Pr)'
note: or       'const _Ty &std::min(const _Ty &,const _Ty &,_Pr)'
note: or       '_Ty std::min(std::initializer_list<_Elem>)'
note: or       'const _Ty &std::min(const _Ty &,const _Ty &)'
```

It seems like a type mismatch, but I don't know how to solve that.

But if you have more elegant solution by using modern C++ mechanism.
Happy to see that!

Comment: You don't need to use a `const` type, initializer_list is immutable

Comment: You probably want to initialize `compare` to `nullptr` in the final `else` case . At least I get an itch when I see uninitialized variables like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the overloads of `std::min` as of C++14:

```
template <class T> constexpr const T& min(const T&, const T&); // (1)
template <class T, class Compare> constexpr const T& min(const T&, const T&, Compare); // (2)
template <class T> constexpr T min(std::initializer_list<T> ); // (3)
template <class T, class Compare> constexpr T min(std::initializer_list<T>, Compare ); // (4)
```

Of those, two only have one single template parameter: `(1)` (which takes two `const T&`s) and `(3)` (which takes a `std::initializer_list<T>`). What you want is `(3)` - but note that it's template parameter is **just `T`**... not `std::initializer_list<T>`. The compiler error is coming about because you're specifying the wrong template function - and neither of the two possible single-template-parameter overloads is assignable to `compare`.

So just fix the way you're specifying it:

```
// not const... just initializer_list<uint32_t>
uint32_t (*compare) (std::initializer_list<uint32_t>);

// select the correct overload
compare = std::min<uint32_t>;
```

This works, because while there are still two overloads named `std::min<uint32_t>` (`(1)` and `(3)`), only `(3)` is actually convertible to `uint32_t(*)(std::initializer_list<uint32_t>)`.

Comment: The explanation helps a lot!